# Google mobile analytics won't log user statistics ios

Tags: ios, mobile, analytics

I followed this tutorial to install google analytics to my app:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios

While my app is open, I show up in the real-time tab of google analytics but when i look at the audience, I don't see any users of the app.

Comment: it will take some time to reflect in Google analytics portal.'Data processing latency: 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 visits per day to Google Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. Daily processing begins at 12:00 UTC and continues for approximately 10 hours. This can  delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days.'

Comment: then why i can see a website analytics logged once i launch the website. Why is this not same with an app